# Kill the running apps automatically

Tags: setting

Is it possible to kill the running apps (SMS, internet explorer, games ...) automatically by turn off the screen or in certain period of time?
My device is huawei and is not rooted
Thanks

Comment: This question is not about programming at all. You could search for a SE site about smartphones and post your question there.

Answer (score -1):

Well, depending on how you wanna define your question yes, there are many.

1. Advanced Task Killer - [Android Apps on Google Play](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.rechild.advancedtaskkiller%26hl%3Den&ei=5alcVba-E83qoATxpoKAAw&usg=AFQjCNGaMI-hQozyu4D-Mg9qnUUCBy1DCA&sig2=mmoD9xl9GmykGZBzbFFhYw&bvm=bv.93756505,d.aWw)
2. Task Killer Free - [Android Apps on Google Play](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dnet.androgames.taskkiller.ad%26hl%3Den&ei=5alcVba-E83qoATxpoKAAw&usg=AFQjCNEV4trTWRedFmGGiu5RDxiUs1heSw&sig2=8X1wY1T04ktRweXncg5tCg&bvm=bv.93756505,d.aWw)
3. Advanced Task Manager - Boost - [Android Apps on Google](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dmobi.infolife.taskmanager%26hl%3Den&ei=5alcVba-E83qoATxpoKAAw&usg=AFQjCNGxIJY9eBaVTTEOpC4ApK3dUZaWAA&sig2=_qV_M7Np2GZ38WiVsEyUSA&bvm=bv.93756505,d.aWw)

Hope it helped.